# How to convert a Map<String,String> to a human readable String (in Dart)?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to convert a Map to a human readable string.

So let's say I have this Map:

```
Map<String, String> map = { "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" };
```

I want to convert it too the following string, including the indents:

```
{
    "foo": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum"
}
```

Comment: Get the key list. Scan that list; for each key extract the corresponding value and print the pair.

Answer (score 11):

use: `new JsonEncoder.withIndent("    ").convert(map)`

From the new dartpad linq with the [same url fragment 685e0fc43fb4e70c602e](https://dartpad.dev/?id=685e0fc43fb4e70c602e)

```dart
import "dart:convert";

main() {
  var map = { "foo": "lorem", "bar": "ipsum" };
  print(new JsonEncoder.withIndent("    ").convert(map));
}
```

see at dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/685e0fc43fb4e70c602e (old link is dead)

Comment: This assumes that the input map is a valid JSON input, that is: the values are simple values. If either keys or values are your own classes, then this conversion won't work without using the extra `toEncodable` parameter as well.

Comment: Link only answers are not ideal. The link above is dead now. But it seems to be fixable

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can convert your map to a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) string.

```
import "dart:convert";

var mapInJsonString = json.encode(map);
```